# How null values was entered to datetime prior to Nullable types?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

`Nullable` types was introduced in **.NET 3.X**. Assume i have DB table with column of type `datetime` that accepts `null` values. If the column data suppose to come from a windows forms client, How do i created a property of type `datetime` and make it accept `null` so i can send `null` values to my DB table column? How this was done in prior versions of .NEt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by your question that you're using a .NET version older than .NET 2.0.

If that's the case you have a few options:

1. Use a "magic" date value to represent "null".  Usually `DateTime.MinValue` or `DateTime.MaxValue`
2. Add a property to your class `IsNull{Column}` (or `{Column}IsNull`}) that would be `true` if the value is "null".

Comment: im not using older version my current is 4.0. I was creating a class but didnt like to put nullable types in it. so i wondered?

Comment: @PhillGreggan What's wrong with nullables? This is starting to sound like an XY problem :)

Comment: Why?  That's what they're for!

Comment: code looks a bit ugly with the nullable and seems weird.. (aesthetics)

Comment: It will look a lot uglier with the "magic value" and/or additional property checks.  Also you know you can just add a `?` to the end instead of using `Nullable<T>` right?

Comment: typically i would manually add a null by checking if the datetime property should be set to null. But its all cool : )

Comment: Strange set of priorities you have if you are basing your application design on the appearance of your code.

Comment: Well, one legitimate problem with `Nullable<T>` is that null `SqlParameter` values are interpreted as "omit this parameter" rather than as "the value of this parameter is null."  So, if you were using a `DateTime?` you'd need to create your SQL parameter value using something like `myNullableDateTime ?? SqlDateTime.Null` or `(object)myNullableDateTime ?? DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 3):

> Nullable types was introduced in .NET 3.X

No, they were introduced in .NET 2.0. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

> How do i created a property of type datetime and make it accept null so i can send null values to my DB table column?

You couldn't. Typically people used a magic value of `DateTime.MinValue` to represent null, and then made sure that their object/database translation layer converted that to a SQL null appropriately. An alternative was to have a separate `bool` property to indicate the presence of a "real" value - or a separate type like [`SqlDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Nullable types in DB have no connection to nullables in C#'s value types. In fact, passing `null` as an argument doesn't count as passing SQL `NULL` - instead, it means "the argument wasn't passed after all" - that's actually a big difference. Instead, you used (and still use) `DBNull.Value`, which is a special value that the DB system understands.

And as Jon says in his answer, on the application layer, you used a magic value, like `DateTime.MinValue`, and just had something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Par", 
    par == DateTime.MinValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : par);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do a lot of hacks, but orginial Solotion is to set ShowCheckBox of the datetTimePicker to true.

So when checkbox is unChecked, the value of datetimepicker will be null.

Comment: What is this suppose to do?

Comment: I just thought that this guy wat to get a Null value from his date time picker.

Comment: There is no mention of a date time picker in the question.